# Javascript modules, loaders, bundlers and package managers confusion

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, bower, browserify

I don't get all the connections. Where do they resides and what is the impact of their usage. Are any of following statments correct?

- the loader will reside in browser(after loaded)? So when the main app javascript needs some module it will load it behind the scenes
- if I use bundler(command line tool) it will create one file from all of my modules(and all common ones used), so no async loading, as there is only the big bundled.js?
- why do I need for example bower.json and package.json in the same project(is npm used just to download build utilities)
- from where do they take the modules (npm repository or all have its own?)
- package managers are just to download the modules to your project for further processing
- npm modules holds only .js files
- you always needs way to orchastrate the build(gulp, grunt, npm scripts)

So far I have not found resource with information like : packagers do that, loaders do that.

Answer (score 1):

> - the loader will reside in browser(after loaded)? So when the main app javascript needs some module it will load it behind the scenes

Loaders is a webpack feature, these loaders are used to process code that webpack does not understand by default (css, sass, images, etc.). They are just used when your code is compiled, when you publish your code it does not contains loaders with it. Loaders just run during build time.

--> Edit: this does not apply to the question since the question refeers to require.js for example, but still relevant overall.

> - if I use bundler(command line tool) it will create one file from all of my modules(and all common ones used), so no async loading, as there is only the big bundled.js?

You can have prefetch, prelight, you can load chunks (pieces of your bundle) only when required (look for code splitting using dynamic import `import(...)`. This makes the code be loadede/requested only when it is going to be loaded.

> - why do I need for example bower.json and package.json in the same project(is npm used just to download build utilities)

Nowadays you don't need bower, most (if not all) the things that bower has you can find on the npm repositories.

> - from where do they take the modules (npm repository or all have its own?)

Every package you download was uploaded to npm, you can look at npm as a "github" but for libraries.

> - packagers are just to download the modules to your project for further processing

Yes

> - npm modules holds only .js files

False, look at bootstrap.

> you always needs way to orchastrate the build(gulp, grunt, npm scripts)

Yes, but if you want to transpile content, you can use only babel-cli.

Comment: I think "loaders" in the question does not relate to webpack loaders but generic JavaScript loaders like head.js, require.js, yepnope.js. Most of them are outdated and deprecated, though. And I might be wrong about what OP meant by "loaders" :)

Comment: I mean package managers  i.e. npm, actually the part which interacts with npm repository

Comment: @str by loaders I mean exactly require.js. Outdated? I really am not able to keep up with javascript.

Comment: I updated my answer, i don't know anything about require.js or something like that, but still relevant information.

Comment: What is the difference between Angular(1) modules and other "dependencies" modules? What format does npm modules have(commonjs, it's own, other)